# Conditionally parameterize SQLite query in AIR

Tags: sqlite, air, parameterization

How can I conditionally parametrize a SQLite database in AIR?
For example this query:

```
//selectedID is the ID I want to select
query.text = "select * from table where id=@ID";
query.parameters['@ID']=selectedID;
```

But I want the `where` statement to appear only if `selectedID` is greater than 0.

What I would normally do is:

```
query.text = "select * from table"+(selectedID>0?" where id="+selectedID:'');
```

However, I read on the LiveDocs performance-wise it is better to use parameters.

Is it possible to parametrize a whole statement or that's only possible for values?
Or maybe this is good-enough:

```
query.text = "select * from table"+(selectedID>0?" where id=@ID":'');
query.parameters['@ID']=selectedID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (selectedID > 0)
            {
                 query.text = .....
                 query.parameters['@ID'] = ...
            } 
            else
            {
                 query.text = .....
            {
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was wondering if you can parameterize the statement.

Comment: Also, it's basically the same thing as with the short version of if-else only I have to change the text property twice when I do...